# Avoiding a global variable

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables

The purpose of the example code below is to be able to restrict a function from printing something via console.log (a loop in this case) if the function is executed twice.

However, the function uses the global variable "condition" and I want to find a way to avoid this. I've been playing around with workarounds, but to no avail. Also, I have checked sources online, but relate to other more complex examples which are beyond my level. This is a simpler example, but haven't been able to crack this.

Grateful for some guidance. Thanks.

```js
let condition = false;

const testFunc = function (value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!condition) {
      console.log(value + i);
    }
  }
  condition = true;
};

testFunc(5);
testFunc(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer is to create yet another scope to hold the state:

```js
function once(fn) {
    let called = false
    return function(...args) {
        if (!called) {
            fn(...args)
            called = true
        }
    }
}


const test = once(function() {
    console.log('hello')
})

test() // hello
test() // nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback - I considered the use of using closure by way of returning a function within another.

Would this be a viable option in order to avoid a global variable? Note that "func" needs to be declared globally -

```js
const testFuncEncaps = function (value) {
  let trueOrFalse = false;

  return function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (!trueOrFalse) {
        console.log(value + i);
      }
    }
    trueOrFalse = true;
  };
};

let func = testFuncEncaps(5);

func();
func();
```